# What are differences between Russian and Ukrainian punctuation rules?

Tags: пунктуація, cross-language-comparison

I know that Russian and Ukrainian punctuation rules are *very* close (if not identical; at least, they're much closer that Russian punctuation rules and English punctuation rules, for example).

Still, I am very interested in the answer: are they absolutely identical (I mean: effects of the rules, not exact their wordings, of course), or no?

Supposing that some person perfectly knows the Russian punctuation: what pitfalls should he be aware of when trying to apply these rules for writing/editing in Ukrainian?

P. S.: I ask about in-sentence and in-text punctuation  (`,` `;` `—` `:` `«»` `()` `.` `?` `!` etc) — not about so-called in-word punctuation (i.e. hyphen and apostrophe: об'єктно-орієнтований), which is (are) actually considered to be a part of spelling rather than punctuation in many language theories.

Answer (score 8):

After going through the list of rules for Russian, and for Ukrainian, and trying to match them up, the following is the list of differences that I found.  At the end of each difference, I make my statement of what is most likely used in the other language for such a case.  If this is incorrect, feel free to correct me-- I do not know Ukrainian as well as most people on here.  If a punctuation mark is not listed (e.g. periods), then its usage is the exact same in both languages.  Also, a few of the differences felt like omissions (i.e. the way I would do it in the other language would be the exact same), so I did not include those.  If this list is incomplete, feel free to complete it.

- Difference for exclamation marks:

Ukrainian:

> 4. Після вигуків, а також після слів так і ні, коли вони стоять на початку речення й вимовляються з виразною окличною інтонацією:

```
Ай! як тут гарно... (Коцюбинський)
```

I am guessing Russian would put a comma in such a case.

---

- Difference for commas:

Ukrainian language and Russian language ask for commas in similar circumstances; however, the rules of Ukrainian language have essentially a list of words before which commas are generally used, whereas Russian describes the actual circumstances in which these words would be used.  See litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm for detailed Ukrainian rules, and therules.ru for the Russian.

A few other rules present in Ukrainian and absent in Russian, were just omissions, since the Russian Bible actually has examples of such phrases.

Note that, in contrast with English, neither Russian nor Ukrainian have a comma before the last word in the list, in case this word is prefixed by "and" or something similar.

---

- Difference for semicolons:

Russian:

> § 135. Точка с запятой ставится в конце рубрик перечисления, если рубрики эти не являются самостоятельными предложениями, но достаточно распространены, и особенно если внутри их уже есть какие-либо знаки препинания, например:

```
Такой способ употребления мин заставил предъявить к ним требования:

    1) чтобы оторвавшаяся от якоря и плавающая на поверхности мина не могла повредить натолкнувшееся на неё судно; 
    2) чтобы при постановке заграждения не было всплывших мин, могущих указать место заграждения, и такие мины тонули; 
    3) увеличить безопасность постановки мин.
(Академик А. Н. Крылов).
```

I believe Ukrainian would dictate using periods in such a case.

---

- Difference for colons:

Russian:

> § 160. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, находящимся в середине предложения, ТОЛЬКО если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово или слова как-то́, например, а именно, например:

```
И всё это: и река, и прутья верболаза, и этот мальчишка — напомнило мне далёкие дни детства (Первенцев).
```

On the other hand, Ukrainian allows colons before all lists in the middle of a sentence.

> § 162. Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединёнными посредством союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать и т. п., делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь описание, например:

```
И вот бакенщик и помощник-киргиз видят: плывут по реке две лодки (А. Н. Толстой).
```

> Но (без оттенка предупреждения):

```
Слышу, земля задрожала (Некрасов).
```

I am guessing Ukrainian would put a dash in such a case.

> § 163. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, вводящего прямую речь, в частности — прямой вопрос или восклицание, например:

```
Минуты две они молчали, но к ней Онегин подошёл и молвил: «Вы ко мне писали, не отпирайтесь» (Пушкин).
```

> Примечание. Группу предложений, в составе которых есть прямая речь, следует отличать от сложных предложений с придаточным: перед придаточным ставится, как обычно, запятая, а в конце его — знак, требуемый характером всего сложного предложения, например:

```
Я думал о том, какой это тяжёлый и ленивый малый.
```

This rule is the same as English; maybe this is an omission in the Ukrainian list of rules?  If not, you would use a dash here.

---

- Difference for dashes:

Russian:

> § 173. Тире ставится для указания места распадения простого предложения на две словесные группы, если другими знаками препинания или порядком слов это не может быть выражено, например:

```
Я вас спрашиваю: рабочим — нужно платить? (Чехов).
```

I believe Ukrainian would not have this sort of phrase construction.

Ukrainian:

> 17. Взагалі для означення спеціально підкреслюваної паузи різного змістового й стилістичного характеру:

```
Увечері кличуть: «Іди до панночки — розбирати» (Марко Вовчок).
Не слухає сонце,
За гору сідає
І нам посилає
На всю ніч — прощай! (Самійленко).
Сьогодні — майбутнього
далину я оком прозираю (Тичина).
На прю ми стали проти царства тьми,
Що оскверняє море й суходоли,
І віримо, що переможем — ми,
І знаємо, що не вмремо — ніколи! (Рильський). /178/
```

### I do not believe Russian would have this type of phrase construction.

- Differences for ellipsis:

> § 187. Многоточие ставится в цитатах:
>
> Для указания, что начало или конец цитаты, являющейся по отношению к окружающему тексту самостоятельным предложением, не совпадает с началом или концом предложения в цитируемом тексте, например:

```
Пушкин, оценивая всех своих предшественников, писал: «...Некоторые оды Державина, несмотря на неправильность языка и неровность слога, исполнены порывами гения...».
```

> Но:

```
Пушкин писал, что «некоторые оды Державина, несмотря на неправильность языка и неровность слога, исполнены порывами гения».
```

Ukrainian would just omit those ellipses in such a case.

---

- Differences for Parentheses:

> У дужки беруться:
>   6. Знак питання або знак оклику в цитатах для вияву ставлення автора до наведеного ним матеріалу (див. § 116, п. 2; § 117, п. 5).
>
> Примітка 1. а) Кома, крапка з комою, двокрапка й тире не ставляться (крім поодиноких специфічних випадків) перед відкритою чи закритою дужкою, а тільки після останньої.
>
> б) Знак питання, знак оклику та крапки можуть стояти перед закритою дужкою, якщо вони безпосередньо відносяться до слів, узятих у дужки; якщо ці знаки стосуються всього речення, їх ставлять після закритої дужки.
>
> Примітка 2. При збігу в реченні внутрішніх і зовнішніх дужок можна в разі потреби застосувати дужки різної форми (круглі та квадратні). При цьому круглі дужки слід ставити в середині квадратних.
>
> Примітка 3. Після цитати, за якою йде в дужках посилання на автора та джерело, крапки не ставимо, а переносимо її за дужки. Проте, коли безпосередньо перед прізвищем автора є вже дужки, крапку слід ставити перед посиланням на автора або джерело:

```
Бувало так, що всю напругу свого таланту Рильський збирав у сонет, і в чотирнадцятьох рядках йому вдавалося дати монументальний образ епохи («Знак терезів — доби нової знак») (Павличко).
```

> Примітка 4. Після закритої дужки, що нею закінчується речення, ставиться розділовий знак, якого вимагає ціле речення, незалежно від того, який знак стоїть перед закритою дужкою.

Russian simply does not have this convention.

Comment: Дякую за Вашу відповідь. Хоча вона й має певні проблеми. По-перше, мене якраз найбільше цікавить різниця саме в комах — як найбільш поширеному розділовому знаку. Чи мені слід створити окреме питання про це, бо тема виявилася занадто широкою?

Comment: По-друге, частиної відповіді є помилкова інформація. Приберіть її, будь ласка. Я зараз напишу ті частини, що я бачу.

Comment: 1. *"Difference for semicolons: […] I believe Ukrainian would dictate using periods in such a case."* — nope. In Ukrainian separator of the list correlates with the case of the next entry's first letter. I.e. we allow both: "1. Hello. 2. World. 3. Bye." — and this: "1) hello; 2) world; 3) bye." Additionally, the letter *must* be capital (and therefore "." must be used) in case when numbering contains period (e.g. "1. " or "I. " — as opposed to "1) ", "a) ", etc). Example: http://dilomova.org.ua/?p=65.

Comment: In fact: a numbered or bulleted list is considered just a fragment of text (either 1 sentence, or many sentences), which is pretty-formatted with new-lines (and optionally bullets). But they still follow common punctuation rules.

Comment: 2. *"Взагалі для означення спеціально підкреслюваної паузи різного змістового й стилістичного характеру: […]. I do not believe Russian would have this type of phrase construction."* — nope, IMHO, it's a typical [интонационное тире (intonational dash; see Rozental, § 7)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94).